# Why doesn't the word 'confirm' have "3rd person -s" in this text?

Tags: grammar

http://www.theguardian.com/football/2014/jul/11/liverpool-luis-suarez-barcelona-transfer-medical

The issue is in the headline 'Liverpool confirm Luis Suárez’s £75m move to Barcelona pending medical'.

Nevertheless It says "A Liverpool statement said: “Liverpool FC confirms that Luis Suárez will ..." in the third paragraph

I don't catch the difference. Can someone explain it to me?

Lot of thanks.

Comment: Guardian seems to write Liverpool-as-a-concept as plural and Liverpool-FC as singular

Comment: In the first sentence,_Liverpool_ stands for "the members of (the management of) the Liverpool football team". It is quite common, especially in BrE, to use the plural when referring to teams, organizations, countries, etc, when you refer to the people _in_ the mentioned group.

Comment: There is a key word overlooked in both comments above: *headline*. It frequently happened in newspapers in the US, and I would expect in the UK, too, that liberties were taken with language usage in headlines to save a few "n"s or "m's of space ("n" and "m" in this usage referring to a measure of width in typography. If "s" is added to "confirm" it would require a smaller size of type to get the headline in that if the s is omitted.